unity Resources.Load naming conflict
Has anyone got trouble when loading resources from path contains various types of resources, such as .cs and .prefab, with the same name?
It's weird that this problem does not always cause errors. In my case, the \VTMenu\VtSystem_AdminMenuItem is ok, but the \VTSystem\VtProductPanelViewItem resulted to an exception of "ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null" and I have to rename the prefab to solve the problem.



VtProductPanelViewItem is a cs file. You mustn't add cs files to your Resources folder. They handled by unity in very different way, than other assets and can't be loaded as a script during runtime.
